# MockitoJunitRunner can mock a Spring @Configuration class but all fields are null

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I have a Configuration class like this :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.**.**") // production code, can't write package name
@EnableCaching
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties", "classpath:version.txt"})
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${builtProfile}")
    @Nonnull
    private String activeProfile;

    ...
}
```

And this is the the test class :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class, MvcConfiguration.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class NativeLoginServiceImplTest {

   @InjectMocks
   private NativeLoginServiceImpl nativeLoginServiceImpl;

   @Mock
   private AppConfig mAppConfiguration;

}
```

The `mAppConfiguration` is created during test but the problem is all of its fields are null. What wrong with my test setup and how can I make the correct one so Mockito can auto get these value in `application.properties` file for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that for your fields you have at least getter methods. You should use `when` and `thenReturn` methods to make mocking work. Like this:

```
@Test
public void someTestMethod(){

    Mockito.when(mAppConfiguration.getActiveProfile()).thenReturn("some value");

    /** actual test goes here**/
}
```

Comment: My senior suggest I use `when` and `thenReturn` too. But I see in the codebase already had a `application.properties` for test profile, so I wonder if I can make mockito auto setup these value for my mock object, I follow some Spring + Mockito guide but none of them work.

Comment: If you want to read values from the properties file then you are performing more an integration test than an unit test. Mockito is used to isolate your class from its dependencies, so to me it's not a good idea to inject a property file in a Mockito test unit.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information, I am still new to the job and haven't been familiar with testing yet.